# Add a user-style to all links with a certain content?

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Newbie question:

I'd like to scan a page for all links where the href starts with `hide?` and then I'd like to add `style="float:left"` to the link like:

```
<a href="hide?6765765" style="float:left">
```

How do I do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. Google any unfamiliar terms (and also "jQuery selectors").

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Float "hide" links
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.

waitForKeyElements ("a[href^='hide?']", floatNodeLeft);

function floatNodeLeft (jNode) {
    jNode.css ("float", "left");
}
```